# Is the Go bytes.Buffer thread-safe?

Tags: go

In the Go programming language, is `bytes.Buffer` thread-safe? AFAIK, [its documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) does not mention thread safety.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No.

The Go documentation follows a simple rule: If it is not explicitly stated that concurrent access to something is safe, it is not.

Comment: Just curious, is that rule documented somewhere?

Comment: @Ztyx sometimes it's more straight to look into the source code and we will easily find no locking operation around bufio `Read`/`Write`

Answer (score 23):

No - but you can easily wrap it in a thread safe struct!

For simple things:

```
type Buffer struct {
    b bytes.Buffer
    m sync.Mutex
}
func (b *Buffer) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.Read(p)
}
func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.Write(p)
}
func (b *Buffer) String() string {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.String()
}
```

..and use it as usual `var buf Buffer`, etc.

Want more of bytes.Buffer? Feel free to cherry pick:

```
func (b *Buffer) Bytes() []byte {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.Bytes()
}
func (b *Buffer) Cap() int {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.Cap()
}
func (b *Buffer) Grow(n int) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    b.b.Grow(n)
}
func (b *Buffer) Len() int {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.Len()
}
func (b *Buffer) Next(n int) []byte {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.Next(n)
}
func (b *Buffer) ReadByte() (c byte, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.ReadByte()
}
func (b *Buffer) ReadBytes(delim byte) (line []byte, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.ReadBytes(delim)
}
func (b *Buffer) ReadFrom(r io.Reader) (n int64, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.ReadFrom(r)
}
func (b *Buffer) ReadRune() (r rune, size int, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.ReadRune()
}
func (b *Buffer) ReadString(delim byte) (line string, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.ReadString(delim)
}
func (b *Buffer) Reset() {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    b.b.Reset()
}
func (b *Buffer) Truncate(n int) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    b.b.Truncate(n)
}
func (b *Buffer) UnreadByte() error {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.UnreadByte()
}
func (b *Buffer) UnreadRune() error {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.UnreadRune()
}
func (b *Buffer) WriteByte(c byte) error {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.WriteByte(c)
}
func (b *Buffer) WriteRune(r rune) (n int, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.WriteRune(r)
}
func (b *Buffer) WriteString(s string) (n int, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.WriteString(s)
}
func (b *Buffer) WriteTo(w io.Writer) (n int64, err error) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()
    return b.b.WriteTo(w)
}
```

Comment: @xiaoyi Why rwmux?

Comment: @JackTuck My up-to-date comment would be `maybe rwmux?`. The `bytes.Buffer` actually changes data in `Read()`, so even with rwmux, a write lock must be used. However, if a different Buffer implementation is used, using rwmux may potentially increase the throughput.

Comment: IMHO, imho, the very usage of mutexes/locks is against the CSP paradigm, isn't it? And CSP is what the Go language is built upon, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

Use `io.Pipe()` function call which provide pair of connected objects (`*PipeReader`, `*PipeWriter`) for synchronous read/write.  This could be done in parallel, and it's a thread-safe.

Comment: It'd be nice if you showed some code. For a newcomer like me, "Use `io.Pipe()`" is a good place to start looking, but it leaves a lot to be done.

Answer (score 0):

bytes.Buffer is not thread safe, but here's an example of writing to a Buffer (or any io.StringWriter) safely using "channels and communication".

```
type SyncWriter struct {
    w      io.StringWriter
    finish sync.WaitGroup
    queue  chan string
    err    error
}

func NewSyncWriter(w io.StringWriter) *SyncWriter {
    var t SyncWriter
    t.w = w
    t.queue = make(chan string, 5)
    t.finish.Add(1)
    go t.writer()
    return &t
}

func (t *SyncWriter) Close() error {
    close(t.queue)
    t.finish.Wait()
    return t.err
}

func (t *SyncWriter) WriteString(s string) (int, error) {
    t.queue <- s
    return len(s), nil
}

func (t *SyncWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return t.WriteString(string(p))
}

func (t *SyncWriter) writer() {
    defer t.finish.Done()
    for s := range t.queue {
        _, err := t.w.WriteString(s)
        if err != nil && t.err == nil {
            t.err = err
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
func write(wg *sync.WaitGroup, w io.Writer, d int) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d", d)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    w := NewSyncWriter(&buf)
    w.WriteString("hello ")
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go write(&wg, w, i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    w.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf.String())
}
```