# Why doesn't os/exec.CombinedOutput() have a race condition?

Tags: go, thread-safety

The Go [`bytes.Buffer` isn't thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19646892/260805). Yet, when I read the source code I notice that [`os/exec.CombinedOutput()`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=12881:12927#L475) uses the same buffer for both `c.Stdout` and `c.Stderr`. Further reading the implementation of the package it looks like there is no synchronisation when writing to the `c.Stderr`/`c.Stdout` [here](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=12881:12927#L254).

Am I missing something or have I found a possible synchronisation issue? AFAIK stderr and stdout can be written to concurrently by the child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stderr and Stdout are not written concurrently if they are the same writer as stated in the [Cmd documentation](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Stdout):

> If Stdout and Stderr are the same writer, at most one goroutine at a time will call Write.

This feature is implemented in the [Cmd.stderr](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go#L226) function. If Stdout and Stderr are the same, then the same fd is passed the child process stdout and stderr. In the case where the fd is a pipe with a goroutine to pump it, there's only one goroutine writing to Stdout/Stderr.

Comment: The documentation is a bit misleading here as there is still a possible race condition when the writers are not comparable. The documentation should probably be updated to be more clear on when exactly Stdout and Stderr are considered "the same". I filled https://golang.org/issue/19804 for this